# Software Developer At A University

Tags: software-industry, career-development

I have just taken a job as a Senior Developer at a well regarded university due to a relocation (will save me 4 hours a day driving to my current job).

I have been told by a number of people at my current employer (which is a fintech business so private sector) that this is a step back in my career as its a public sector role and will not look good on my CV.

I was wondering what peoples thoughts were on this based on your experience? I know there is going to be pros and cons which each but I am a little worried that I have made the wrong decision.

Thanks For Helping!

Comment: If it saves you 4 hours per day, I would take it. There's tons of things you can do with *time* that no *money* will ever be able to do. But that's my personal opinion.

Comment: VTC career advice, I'm not sure even the general question of "How are IT jobs in Academia seen?" is on-topic. That said, when anyone from your current employer tells you stuff like this it's almost always worthless and should be ignored.

Comment: Out of curiosity (and it could also be very relevant): what exactly will you be doing at the university ?

Comment: @RaduMurzea the OP states the answer to your question in the first sentence.

Comment: There can only be so much truth to this kind of advice, because whatever is a step back in someone else career might quite well be a step forward in your career. Because it is about your goals and wishes.

Comment: @MisterPositive What I meant is that, when you get hired as a developer at a university, it's a difference between helping research teams building software for testing their theories as opposed to doing some web-design for the university's website.

Comment: @RaduMurzea They have a number of projects on the go which does include a rotation of BAU(Business As Usual)  which is to support they older systems. They currently have a greenfield project which is using the latest .NetCore framework and Angular 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you took a job at a university as a Sr. Software Developer is not a step back in your career.

As a software developer what matters most is that you are working with relevant technologies in the market as a whole.

If you are working with older, outdated technologies then yes, it may be a step back in your career -- but that would be the case regardless if you were going to work for a university or another software development firm.

Comment: they have a mixture of old and new technologies which I guess is true about any company. They do allow a day each sprint (they are using Scrum) to work on whatever you like to increase you knowledge.

Comment: Old tech isn't necessarily bad, learning a diverse range of tech is best IMO. There are plenty of companies out there using older technologies so I wouldn't fret about that. Learn what you can and move on.

Comment: You have to balance their technology stack with what is currently being used in the market. As you said most places have a bit of newer and older tech, just avoid the ancient.

Comment: There are plenty of legacy systems out there with very few people who have the knowledge to use and maintain them.  This is not a step back, it is an expansion of your knowledge base.

Comment: @RichardU Agreed, in as long as its not the ONLY thing your working on.  Should that job go away, and say a few years pass, you will be hard pressed in general to be marketable.

Comment: @RichardU Mister Positive. You're right, it will expand my knowledge on how to maintain legacy systems and also my investigative and debugging skills. I will get to work on greenfield projects that use the latest tech but this job will also give me more time to do personal development and will allow me to keep up with the market that way.